# password_verify() does not work

Tags: php, mysql

Unfortunately I did not find the solution to the problem that I am a beginner, and I do not know why this function does not work and how I will use it. If someone gives me the solution written to understand the code and the problem please. (PS: dsl for just google translation)

```
(//Really 20 hours I try. No solution...(page login)
  if (isset($_POST['connexion']))
{ $pseudoconnect=htmlspecialchars($_POST['pseudoconnect']);
$passwordconnect=htmlspecialchars($_POST['passwordconnect']);
if (!empty('$pseudoconnect') AND !empty('$passwordconnect'))
{
$pseudoconnectlenght=strlen($pseudoconnect) ;
$passwordconnectlenght=strlen($passwordconnect) ;
if ($pseudoconnectlenght<3 || $pseudoconnectlenght>10 || $passwordconnectlenght<3 || $passwordconnectlenght >10)
{               
echo "remplis tous les infos exacte";
}
else
{                       
$repnom = $connect->prepare("SELECT password FROM membres WHERE pseudo=? ");
$repnom->execute(array($passwordconnect));
$userinfo= $repnom->fetch();
$_SESSION['password']= $userinfo['password'];
if (password_verify($_POST['passwordconnect'], $userinfo['password']))
{
echo "valid";
} else {
echo "pas valid";}}}
```

(page registration work correctly) I use `password_hash` and its function well.. PS: dsl for just google translation)

```
if (isset($_POST['envoyer'])) 
        {


            if (!empty($_POST['pseudo']) AND !empty($_POST['password'])) 
            {
                    $pseudo=htmlspecialchars($_POST['pseudo']);
                    $password=htmlspecialchars($_POST['password']);
                    //$password=password_hash('password',PASSWORD_DEFAULT,['cost'=>12]);

                      $pseudolenght=strlen($pseudo);
                      $passwordlenght=strlen($password);
                      /*verifier les champs */
                        if ($pseudolenght<4 ||$pseudolenght>10 || $passwordlenght<4 || $passwordlenght> 10 ) 
                          { 

                                            echo "pass ou pseudo pas correct";
                           }    
                                else //enregistrement et verifier pseudo
                                    {

                                        $repetepseudo = $connect->prepare("SELECT * FROM membres WHERE pseudo=?");
                                        $repetepseudo->execute(array($pseudo));
                                        $existpseudo = $repetepseudo->rowCount();
                                        //verifier pseudo si déja existe
                                                if ($existpseudo == 0 )
                                                    {
                                                        //hasher password

                                                        $hash=password_hash($password,PASSWORD_DEFAULT,['cost'=>12]);

                                                        $sql = "INSERT INTO membres (pseudo,password) VALUES (?,?)";
                                                        $query = $connect->prepare($sql);
                                                        $query->execute(array($pseudo,$hash));





                                                            echo "enregistrement valide";
                                                            //header('location: html.php');

                                                     }

                                                        else
                                                            {
                                                                echo "déja utiliser";
                                                    }
                                                    }


                                                            }  //if empty
                                                                    else {

                                                                                echo "remplir tous les champs ";
                                                                          }





                                                                                                }//if isset eenvoyer
```

Comment: sorry create code does not work for me

Comment: Past your code here, not pictures...

Comment: Also what doesn't work, that is a broad statement

Comment: You use `htmlspecialchars()` on the input? And you always hash and insert the string 'password', not a variable.

Comment: And singlequotes around variables makes them *strings*, not variables.

Comment: (ag)..Plz someone just writes the line that, I will change.
(fr). plz quelqu'un écrit  juste la ligne que, je vais changer .

Comment: @z.yastos paste the text, someone will format it for you.

Comment: Honestly, you expect this question to help anyone? Post your real code instead of images of it. You were asked hours ago to do this and did not update your question.

Comment: Please add code, errors and data as **text** ([using code formatting](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code)), not images. Images: A) don't allow us to copy-&-paste the code/errors/data for testing; B) don't permit searching based on the code/error/data contents; and [many more reasons](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557). In general, code/errors/data in text format >>>> code/errors/data as an image >> nothing.  Images should only be used, *in addition to text in code format*, if having the image adds something significant that is not conveyed by just the text code/error/data.

Comment: (Really 20 hours i try. No solution(part code)) 
if (isset($_POST['connexion'])) 
$pseudoconnect=htmlspecialchars($_POST['pseudoconnect']); 
$passwordconnect=htmlspecialchars($_POST['passwordconnect']);
if (!empty('$pseudoconnect') AND !empty('$passwordconnect')) {
 $repnom = $connect->prepare("SELECT password FROM membres WHERE pseudo=? "); $repnom->execute(array($passwordconnect));
$userinfo= $repnom->fetch();
$_SESSION['password']= $userinfo['password'];
if (password_verify($_POST['passwordconnect'], $userinfo['password'])) { echo "valid";} else { echo "pas valid";}} }

Comment: @z.yastos updated my answer for your updated question, you were supplying the wrong param to your query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to retrieve the password from the database matching on the username.

```
SELECT password FROM members WHERE psuedo = ?
```

Then validate the supplied password matching the username.

```
if (password_verify($_POST['password'], $userInfo['password'])) {
    //... valid user
} else {
   //... invalid user
}
```

If it returns `true`, it means the username and password entered matches the user in the database.

If your `pseudo` column is not unique (which I see you check for), you would need to iterate over all of the users to find the password that passes `password_verify`.

The reason is `password_hash` generates a unique salt every time it is called, causing the generated hashed password to be different. Making it impossible to query the password stored in the database.

So this will not work

```
var_dump(password_hash('test', \PASSWORD_DEFAULT) === password_hash('test', \PASSWORD_DEFAULT)); //false
```

Result: https://3v4l.org/jM4YH

Additionally, you need to change your `password_hash` usage to:

```
$hash = password_hash($password, \PASSWORD_DEFAULT, ['cost' => 12]);
```

As it is currently, every user's password would be the word `password` and not the password they supplied.

---

As a note, you should also utilize [password_needs_rehash](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-needs-rehash.php) after verification, of which an example of a successful login is on the page. This will ensure passwords are maintained for security updates released by PHP.

---

**Updated**

*With the question modified to match my suggestions.*

You need to retrieve the password from the database, by matching the user to the one supplied.

```
$repnom = $connect->prepare("SELECT password FROM membres WHERE pseudo = ?");
$repnom->execute(array($passwordconnect));
```

Should be sending the `pseudo` param, not the `password` param

```
$repnom->execute(array($pseudoconnect));
```

Also since you run `htmlspecialchars` on the password saved in the database, you should use the same on `password_verify`

```
$passwordconnect = htmlspecialchars($_POST['passwordconnect']);

//...

password_verify($passwordconnect, $userinfo['password']);
```